# Any way to format external sd card as FAT?

Tags: external-sd, reformat

I've been searching on Google to find a way to format an external sd card in FAT file format, but I didn't find anything. Every links were asking for FAT32 or EXT4.

I use AndroidM. Recovery is TWRP 3.0.2-0 (if my memory's good).

I don't have any computer, so that's why I'm trying to do it on my phone.

Thanks in advance.

Update: my device is rooted.

Comment: Have you tried aParted in the Play Store? I don't have a card small enough to test if it does straight fat or only fat32 though, fat12 max out at 32MB and fat16 at 2GB.

Comment: @acejavelin yes I did , but unfortunately it doesn't do FAT.

Comment: Use `mkdosfs` or `mkfs.vfat` commands from Terminal.. See its documentation for usage..

Comment: @GokulNC isn't this for FAT32?

Comment: No, it also supports FAT16.. [Check the docs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkdosfs)